# Basic- kernel written in basic

Tags: kernel, basic

I have read somewhere that higher level languages are not good to create kernels, So my question is, Can we make Kernel in Basic, the simplest language?

Comment: Consider googling terms `Turing completeness` and `Meta-circular evaluator`. :-)

Comment: "the simplest language" doesn't mean "low-level language". A programming language which is the lowest level is *assembler*, and one need to use it for at least a part of the kernel's code. For the other part of the kernel almost any progamming language could be used.

Comment: In case @Tsyvarev wasn't clear, BASIC **is** a high-level language by definition.  If you really want to write a Kernel in "the simplest language" consider the challenge of writing in machine language.

Comment: Basic is a high-level language, C/C++/C# is a mid-level language, Assembly is a low-level language, which language is "simple" is not defined. You could probably NOT write a Kernel in Basic..

Comment: Thanks everyone here for feedback